# Monitoring in SL

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am implementing Monitoring functions, such as Add monitor, Add users and Edit monitoring.. (refer to attached file)
To get users to notify, I've called getEligibleAlarmSubscibers(), but no data has been retrieved.  Can you provide me any sample code in java to implement monitorings(Add Monitor, Add users, List Existing monitorings)?

```
List<Agent> agentList = guest.getMonitoringAgents();


        for(Agent agent:agentList){

            System.out.println(" ******************************* " );
            System.out.println(" agent Name  : " + agent.getName());
            System.out.println(" agent Id  : " + agent.getId());

            List<Customer> custList = agent.asService(client).getEligibleAlarmSubscibers();

            for(Customer customer :custList){
                System.out.println(" ******************************* " );
                System.out.println(" Eligible Customer username : " + customer.getUsername());
                System.out.println(" Eligible Customer Email : " + customer.getEmail());
                System.out.println(" Eligible Customer First name : " + customer.getFirstName());       
            }   
        }
```

[image: Monitoring]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. To get monitors you should try the following methods:**

- For Hardware:

  - [SoftLayer_Hardware::getNetworkMonitors](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware/getNetworkMonitors)
- For Virtual Guest

  - [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getNetworkMonitors](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getNetworkMonitors)

> Updated

Here an example for hardware:

```
package Monitoring;

import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.Hardware;
import com.softlayer.api.service.network.monitor.version1.query.Host;

/**
 * This script retrieve monitors from a server
 *
 * Important Manual Page:
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware/getObject
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Search_Result
 *
 * @license <http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License>
 * @authon SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
 * @version 0.2.2
 */
public class GetMonitorsFromServer {
    /**
     * This is the constructor, is used to get monitors
     */
    public GetMonitorsFromServer() {
        // Declare your SoftLayer username and apiKey
        String username = "set me";
        String apiKey = "set me";

        ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apiKey);
        // Declare the hardware Id
        Long hardwareId = new Long(92862);
        // Define SoftLayer_Hardware_Server service
        Hardware.Service hardwareService = Hardware.service(client, hardwareId);
        // Define an object mask
        hardwareService.withMask().networkMonitors();
        hardwareService.withMask().networkMonitors().id();
        hardwareService.withMask().networkMonitors().ipAddress();
        hardwareService.withMask().networkMonitors().queryType();
        hardwareService.withMask().networkMonitors().responseAction();
        hardwareService.withMask().networkMonitors().lastResult();
        hardwareService.withMask().networkMonitors().status();
        hardwareService.withMask().networkMonitors().waitCycles();


        try {
            Hardware hardware = hardwareService.getObject();

            for(Host host : hardware.getNetworkMonitors())
            {
                System.out.println("Id: " + host.getId());
                System.out.println("Primary IP: " + host.getIpAddress());
                System.out.println("Monitor Type: " + host.getQueryType().getName());
                System.out.println("Notify: " + host.getResponseAction().getActionDescription());
                System.out.println("Notify Wait: " + host.getWaitCycles());
                System.out.println("Status: " + host.getStatus());
                System.out.println("-------------------------");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is the main method which makes use of GetMonitorsFromServer method.
     *
     * @param args
     * @return Nothing
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GetMonitorsFromServer();
    }


}
```

**2. To add a monitor, you should use the following method:**

- [SoftLayer_Network_Monitor_Version1_Query_Host::createObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Monitor_Version1_Query_Host/createObject)

Here an example for Hardware:

```
package Monitoring;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.network.monitor.version1.query.Host;

/**
 * This script adds a monitor
 *
 * Important Manual Page:
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Monitor_Version1_Query_Host/createObject
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Monitor_Version1_Query_Host
 *
 * @license <http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License>
 * @authon SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
 * @version 0.2.2
 */
public class AddMonitor {
    /**
     * This is the constructor, is used to Add Monitor
     */
    public AddMonitor() {
        // Declare your SoftLayer username and apiKey
        String username = "set me";
        String apiKey = "set me";

        // Define Hardware identifier
        Long hardwareId = new Long(92862);
        // Define Ip Address
        String ipAddress = "10.60.9.72";
        // Define Query Type (1 = SERVICE PING, 17 = SLOW PING)
        Long queryTypeId = new Long(1);
        // Define Response action id (1 = Do Nothing, 2 = Notify Users)
        Long responseActionId = new Long(2);
        // Define waitCycles 0 = Immediately, 1 = 5 Minutes, 2 = 10 Minutes, etc
        Long waitCycles = new Long(1);

        // Create client
        ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apiKey);

        // Define SoftLayer_Network_Monitor_Version1_Query_Host service
        Host.Service hostService = Host.service(client);

        // Build a SoftLayer_Network_Monitor_Version1_Query_Host object that you wish to create
        Host templateObject = new Host();
        templateObject.setHardwareId(hardwareId);
        templateObject.setIpAddress(ipAddress);
        templateObject.setQueryTypeId(queryTypeId);
        templateObject.setResponseActionId(responseActionId);
        templateObject.setWaitCycles(waitCycles);
        try {
            Host result = hostService.createObject(templateObject);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            System.out.println(gson.toJson(result));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is the main method which makes use of AddMonitor method.
     *
     * @param args
     * @return Nothing
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AddMonitor();
    }


}
```

If you want to add a monitor for Virtual Guest, you should define **guestId** instead of **hardwareId**.

**3. To add users to notify:**

- For Hardware

  - [SoftLayer_User_Customer_Notification_Hardware::createObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer_Notification_Hardware/createObject)
- For Virtual Guest

  - [SoftLayer_User_Customer_Notification_Virtual_Guest::createObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer_Notification_Virtual_Guest/createObject)

Here an example using [SoftLayer_User_Customer_Notification_Hardware::createObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer_Notification_Hardware/createObject):

```
package Monitoring;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.user.customer.notification.Hardware;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * This script adds a users to notify.
 *
 * Important Manual Page:
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer_Notification_Hardware/createObjects
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain
 *
 * @license <http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License>
 * @authon SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
 * @version 0.2.2
 */
public class AddUsersToNotify {
    /**
     * This is the constructor, is used to Add users to notify
     */
    public AddUsersToNotify() {
        // Declare your SoftLayer username and apiKey
        String username = "set me";
        String apiKey = "set me";

        // Define the hardware and user identifiers
        Long hardwareId = new Long(92862);
        Long userId = new Long(141202);

        // Create client
        ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apiKey);

        // Define SoftLayer_User_Customer_Notification_Hardware service
        Hardware.Service hardwareService = Hardware.service(client);

        // Declare SoftLayer_User_Customer_Notification_Hardware List
        List<Hardware> templateObjects = new ArrayList<Hardware>();

        // Build a SoftLayer_User_Customer_Notification_Hardware objects that you wish to create
        Hardware templateObject = new Hardware();
        templateObject.setUserId(userId);
        templateObject.setHardwareId(hardwareId);

        // Add templateObject to templateObjects
        templateObjects.add(templateObject);

        try {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Hardware results = hardwareService.createObject(templateObject);
            System.out.println(gson.toJson(results));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is the main method which makes use of AddUsersToNotify method.
     *
     * @param args
     * @return Nothing
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AddUsersToNotify();
    }


}
```

I hope it really help you.

Comment: As I see, you want some examples to get user to notify and edit monitors

Comment: Thanks a lot.. but when adding a monitor it returns "Error: com.softlayer.api.ApiException$Internal: Unable to create a new object of type SoftLayer_Network_Monitor_Version1_Query_Host. Make sure the authentication method is correct.(code: SoftLayer_Exception, status: 500)"

Comment: Did you set your username, apiKey and change hardwareId, userId and IpAddress with your own information?

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure what can be the issue, can you share the code that you tried? (without your credentials)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113422/discussion-between-ruber-cuellar-and-mike-oh).

Comment: I've posted what I did

Comment: Due to the security policy here, I can't move to chat.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried to add a monitor..

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.monitoring.Agent;
import com.softlayer.api.service.user.Customer;
import com.softlayer.api.service.virtual.Guest;

import com.softlayer.api.service.Hardware;
import com.softlayer.api.service.network.monitor.version1.query.Host;

    private void AddMonitoringInfo(){

        Long hardwareId = new Long(848429);
        // Define Ip Address
        String ipAddress = "173.192.36.250";
        // Define Query Type (1 = SERVICE PING, 17 = SLOW PING)
        Long queryTypeId = new Long(1);
        // Define Response action id (1 = Do Nothing, 2 = Notify Users)
        Long responseActionId = new Long(2);
        // Define waitCycles 0 = Immediately, 1 = 5 Minutes, 2 = 10 Minutes, etc
        Long waitCycles = new Long(1);


        // Define SoftLayer_Network_Monitor_Version1_Query_Host service
        Host.Service hostService = Host.service(client);

        // Build a SoftLayer_Network_Monitor_Version1_Query_Host object that you wish to create
        Host templateObject = new Host();
        templateObject.setHardwareId(hardwareId);
        templateObject.setIpAddress(ipAddress);
        templateObject.setQueryTypeId(queryTypeId);
        templateObject.setResponseActionId(responseActionId);
        templateObject.setWaitCycles(waitCycles);
        try {
              Host result = hostService.createObject(templateObject);

              Gson gson = new Gson();
              System.out.println(gson.toJson(result));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }

    }
```

Comment: That I see, the hardware doesn't belong to any account, probably you changed this for security, can you submit a ticket to SoftLayer with the full code that you tried?

Comment: I've updated hardwareId, but I've got same result. can you try again

Comment: Now, I see the changes, let me check

Comment: Your code should work fine, as I see, the user with which you are trying to create the monitor, should have "Manage Device Monitoring" permission enabled, please check this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to edit:

```
package Monitoring;

import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.network.monitor.version1.query.Host;

/**
 * This script edits a monitor
 *
 * Important Manual Page:
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Monitor_Version1_Query_Host/editObject
 *
 * @license <http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License>
 * @authon SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
 * @version 0.2.2
 */
public class EditMonitor {
    /**
     * This is the constructor, is used to Add Monitor
     */
    public EditMonitor() {
        // Declare your SoftLayer username and apiKey
        String username = "set me";
        String apiKey = "set me";

        // Define Hardware identifier
        Long hostId = new Long(3514022);
        // Define Query Type (1 = SERVICE PING, 17 = SLOW PING)
        Long queryTypeId = new Long(17);
        // Define Response action id (1 = Do Nothing, 2 = Notify Users)
        Long responseActionId = new Long(1);
        // Define waitCycles 0 = Immediately, 1 = 5 Minutes, 2 = 10 Minutes, etc
        Long waitCycles = new Long(0);

        // Create client
        ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apiKey);

        // Define SoftLayer_Network_Monitor_Version1_Query_Host service
        Host.Service hostService = Host.service(client, hostId);

        // Build a SoftLayer_Network_Monitor_Version1_Query_Host object that you wish to edit
        Host templateObject = new Host();
        templateObject.setQueryTypeId(queryTypeId);
        templateObject.setResponseActionId(responseActionId);
        templateObject.setWaitCycles(waitCycles);

        try {
            boolean  result = hostService.editObject(templateObject);
            System.out.println(result);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is the main method which makes use of AddMonitor method.
     *
     * @param args
     * @return Nothing
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new EditMonitor();
    }


}
```

You should specify the **hostId** (Monitor id that you wish to edit), I updated the getMonitors script, in order to provide the ids, see **getMonitorsFromServer** script please, in my first answer